Intermediate Value Theorem on a Tree
Suppose we have a finite tree $T$ and a continuous function $f:[0,1]\to |T|$. By $|T|$ I mean the underlying space which we can think of as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$. It seems intuitively obvious that given a $t\in |T|$ "between" $f(0)$ and $f(1),$ there should be a $c\in(0,1)$ such that $f(c)=t$. By "between" I mean $t$ is a point on the unique non self intersecting path from $f(0)$ to $f(1)$.
My questions:

Is there a standard notion of "betweenness" on trees?

Is the intermediate value theorem on trees a special case of a general intermediate value theorem from topology?


I know that continuous functions preserve connectedness, so $f([0,1])$ is a connected subspace of the tree. Intuitively, I know that if there is a point "between" $f(0)$ and $f(1)$ missing from $f([0,1])$, then it's not connected.
I also found a generalization of the IVT for a continuous $f:X\to Y$ where $X$ is a topological space and $Y$ is an ordered set with the order topology, but to use it I'd need an order on my tree. I suspect that the problem of giving $T$ the correct order is related to the problem of defining what I mean by "between."

There are not that many continuous functions $f:[0,1] \to A$, where $A$ is a finite set. And they are all constant.

To clarify, I'm thinking of a tree as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$, not as a set of edges and vertices, and so I mean a continuous function with respect to the subspace topology.

I would put that in the main question if I were you

For your second question: how general do you mean? The standard "general intermediate value theorem" is that continuous functions preserve connecteness, but you've mentioned that already.

Topological trees, like trees, are disconnected by the removal on any of their vertices, so if $c \notin Im(f)$ but $a$ and $b$ both are, $Im(f)$ must be disconnected. There's a unique path $a$ to $b$, up to parameterisation, so there can't be a second path in $Im(f)$ connecting $a$ to $b$.

@ZoeAllen I see, thanks. To turn this into a proof, I guess I'd need to argue that $Im(f)$ is also a topological tree? Perhaps we could say that every connected subspace of a tree is itself a tree?

@ZoeAllen "There is a unique path up to parameterization." That seems to be the crux of the matter. In this case, I'm guessing "path" means non self intersecting path to rule out paths that go down another branch and come back.

I think your conclusion is a satisfactory definition of betweenness (i.e. define "$c$ is between $a$ and $b$" to mean every path from $a$ to $b$ goes through $c$). An alternative definition might be that $a$ and $b$ are in different connected components (= path components) of $T \setminus {c}$, but it's easy to see that these are equivalent conditions (if $c \ne a,b$).

@arkeet Thank you. Are you aware of any references on topological trees that might flesh out the details of statements like "there is a unique path" from a to b (if we define path appropriately)?

I am not sure what you meant by a finite tree then.

@arkeet perhaps I'm mistaken, but I thought the intention was to use betweenness in the tree as the definition of betweenness of nodes in the topological tree

If there is a unique path up to paramaterisation to start with, removing points can't add new paths so paths will still be unique in a subspace

@copper.hat I meant finitely many edges and vertices.

@H_R I'm not sure about uniqueness of paths exactly, but any reasonable reference on topology should explain how an abstract graph can be realized as a topological space (specifically, a quotient space given by vertex points and line segments, with each endpoint glued to a vertex, i.e. a "1-dimensional CW complex"), and a graph is a tree iff its realization is simply connected (which is to say there is a unique path between any two points up to homotopy). Munkres, for example, has this.

@arkeet Thanks. So the argument is: T is simply connected. Thus f:[0,1]->R is homotopy equivalent to a direct path from f(0) to f(1). ??? Profit.

I dunno, what special property of a tree is being used in this proof? Why wouldn't this proof apply to $f : [0,1] \to \mathbb R^2$?

@Lee Mosher The issue is what we mean by "between." The basic idea of the IVT is given continuous f:[a,b] -> R, given any y between f(a) and f(b), we can find an x between  a and b such that f(x)=y. In R^2, it's unclear what we would mean be between. On a tree, we could define between to mean on the unique "direct path" from f(a) to f(b).
Edit: I just realized you're not saying the result is true in R^2, you're saying the proof would apply just as well to R^2, so it must be missing something.

The answers to your questions are both yes. For any tree $T$, any two points $x \ne y \in |T|$, and any subspace $A \subset T$, let's say that $A$ is a subarc with endpoints $x,y$ if there exists a homeomorphism $f : [0,1] \to A$ such that $f(0)=x$ and $f(1)=y$.
Theorem For any two points $x \ne y \in |T|$ there exists a unique subarc $A \subset |T|$ with endpoints $x,y$. Furthemore, denoting $A=[x,y]$, and $(x,y)=[x,y] - \{x,y\}$, for any point $z \in (x,y)$ the points $x,y$ are in different path components of $|T|-\{z\}$.
Roughly speaking, this theorem is telling you the meaning of the "betweeness" property that you want: the theorem says that if $z$ is between $x$ and $y$ in the sense that $z  \in (x,y)$ then $z$ is contained in the image of any path from $x$ to $y$.
This theorem is true even for infinite trees, although the proof is more intricate. For finite trees, there is a simple proof by induction on the number of edges of $T$. The basis step is when $T$ has one edge and is homeomorphic to $[0,1]$, where the proof reduces to the ordinary IVT of calculus. For the induction step one uses the fact that there is a subtree $T' \subset T$ and an edge $E \subset |T|$ such that $T'$ has one fewer edge than $T$, and $|T|=|T'| \cup E$, and $|T'| \cap E$ is a single vertex; one then applies the induction hypothesis to $T'$.

Thank you, Professor Mosher. This is exactly what I was looking for. Do you know of any references with this result?

Not particularly. It is part of Exercise 1.2.1.3 in my book.
